# Phalcon - validation in form

Tags: php, forms, validation, phalcon

I created a form with validation rules. Everything is fine, form is visible and works.
Problem is with validators. Only first validator works in `addValidators([ ....])`

My form class source code:

```
public function initialize()
{

    $title = new Text('title');
    $title->setLabel('Title of article');
    $title->setFilters([
        'striptags', 'trim'
    ]);

    $title->addValidators([
        new PresenceOf([
            'message' => 'Title can not be empty'
        ]),
        new StringLength([
            'min' => 5,
            'messageMinimum' => 'Title is too short. Should has more than 5 letters'
        ]),
        new MYArticleAddCheckTitleValidator([
            'message' => 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
        ])
    ]);

    $this->add($title);

    ..........
```

- Validator PresenceOf works fine. validation flash message is visible.
- Validator StringLength does not work. It looks like form doesn't know about it
- Validator MYArticleAddCheckTitleValidator (my own validator class) - the same as StringLength.

Phalcon version 2.0.4 on windows.

Any proposition, or suggestions ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I dont see the solution. But your second validation I belive should be "at least 5 letter" or "more than 4 letters" because 5 is a valid input.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your own class and also the part where you actually do the Test?
Have you tried to use the simple way of adding each validator on its own?
Can you change the order of the validators to see if only PresenceOf or only the first validator works?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Phalcon\Flash\Direct

The best way to get around this problem is to use flash messages, with the class `Phalcon\Flash\Direct`. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Flash_Direct.html).

This strategy is used by the phalcon [vokuro project](https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro) which I suggest you to look at.

The key of this solution is the `message()` function inside your form class.

**Form class**

```
<?php
namespace Your\App\Forms;

use Phalcon\Forms\Form;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text;
use Phalcon\Validation\Message;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\StringLength;
use Your\App\Validation\MYArticleAddCheckTitleValidator;

class YourForm extends Form {

    public function initialize()
    {

        $title = new Text('title');
        $title->setLabel('Title of article');
        $title->setFilters([
            'striptags', 'trim'
        ]);

        $title->addValidators([
            new PresenceOf([
                'message' => 'Title can not be empty'
            ]),
            new StringLength([
                'min' => 5,
                'messageMinimum' => 'Title is too short. Should has more than 5 letters'
            ]),
            new MYArticleAddCheckTitleValidator([
                'message' => 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
            ])
        ]);

        $this->add($title);
    }

    /**
     * Prints messages for a specific element. Call it in the view
     */
    public function messages($name)
    {
        if ($this->hasMessagesFor($name)) {
            foreach ($this->getMessagesFor($name) as $message) {
                $this->flash->error($message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace Your\App;

use Your\App\YourForm;

class YourController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
       $form = new YourForm();
       $this->view->form = $form;

        if($this->request->hasQuery('title')){
            if ($form->isValid($this->request->getQuery()) != false) {
                // Code when form is valid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**
If you follow the suggested schema should be located in `/app/views/your/index.html`

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <?= $form->label('title') ?>
    <?= $form->render('title')?>
    <?= $form->messages('title') //show messages here ?>
</form>
```

If you have more than one form, it is useful to register the flash service with the `DI`.
When you define your services (could be in the `index.php` in the root folder or `services.php` in the `/app/config/` folder) you define your flash service:

```
<?php 
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;

$di = new FactoryDefault();

// Register the flash service with custom CSS classes
$di->set('flash', function () {
    $flash = new Phalcon\Flash\Direct(
        array(
            'error'   => 'your-error-class',
            'success' => 'your-success-class',
            'notice'  => 'your-notice-class',
            'warning' => 'your-warning-class'
        )
    );

    return $flash;
});
```